# Is this upper bound correct for DCT?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

I am reading a paper which wants to use the dominated convergence theorem and needs to find an integrable upper bound $g(y)$. It introduces the function 
$$g(y)=\min{\left\{1,\frac{1}{y^2}\right\}}$$
and claims that $$p(y\mid x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2} \exp{\left(\frac{-y}{1+x^2}\right)}\leq g^2(y), \quad\forall x\geq 0, y\geq 0$$

Is this claim correct? I plot this for different values of $x$ and it doesn't seem right. Am I missing something?

By the way, the DCT is for some other function (not mentioned here, not relevant to my question) so don't get puzzled why it works with $g^2(y)$.

Comment: It doesn't seem correct to me. What paper is this from?

Comment: did you try with $g(g(y))$ ?

Comment: @user1952009, $g(g(y))=1, \forall y\geq 0$ right, but in the paper (mentioned above) I guess it really needs $g^2(y)$ since it is the bound on function $f^2(y)$ that it wants to use DCT for.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p(y,x)\leqslant 1$ for $x,y\geqslant 0$, the question reduces to know whether the inequality 
$$\tag{*}\frac{1}{1+x^2} \exp\left(\frac{-y}{1+x^2}\right)\leqslant \frac 1{y^4}$$
holds for any $x,y\geqslant 0$. If we take $y=1+x^2$, then (*) implies that $$\frac 1{1+x^2}\leqslant \frac 1{(1+x^2)^4}$$
for any $x\geqslant 0$ which cannot be truefor $x\neq 0$.